# Pass reference instance to static method when copy-constructor and assignment-operator is disabled

Tags: c++, class, copy-constructor, assignment-operator

My ClassA looks like this:

```
class ClassA
{
private:
    static uint32_t IDCOUNTER;
    uint32_t _id = -1;

public:
    ClassA();
    ~ClassA();
    ClassA(const ClassA&) = delete;
    void operator=(const ClassA&) = delete;
};
```

I want to create one specific instance of ClassA and I want it to be passed around but I don't want it to ever be duplicated in any way. So, in my main function I instantiate instanceA1.
Next, (in my main function), I want to store this instance somewhere global, like in a static class:

```
int main()
{
    ClassA instanceA1;
    ClassStatic::SetClassA(&instanceA1);
}


// this class is declared in a separate file:
class ClassStatic
{
private:
    static ClassA *referenceToA;

public:
    static void SetClassA(ClassA* refToSingleAInstance)
    {
        referenceToA = refToSingleAInstance; // taken from cpp part of the class just for this question
    }
};
```

When compiling, I get a linker error. Why is that? Am I getting the whole concept wrong (seems likely...)? How would I fix this?

Comment: You may wan to look a the "Singleton Pattern" and how it is usually implemented...

Comment: Where you defined IDCOUNTER? and referenceToA?

Comment: @AliRazmkhah I defined it in the ClassA.cpp file. But I forget to initialize referenceToA with nullptr or sth. like that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> When compiling, I get a linker error. Why is that?

Because you didn't define `ClassStatic::referenceToA`.

> How would I fix this?

Define `ClassStatic::referenceToA` in (exactly one) translation unit.

Comment: Didn't I define it with: static ClassA *referenceToA;. ?

Comment: @AudioGuy No. If that was the definition, then you'd have problems including the class definition into multiple translation units given that One Definition Rule does not allow defining a variable in more than one TU.

Comment: So I should do ClassStatic::referenceToA =nullptr in the cpp file? Sorry, I am new to c++ ;-)

Comment: I will try as soon as I get back to my PC. I will keep you updated.